# Can I leave out the word "of" in a situation like "all of his works"?

Tags: prepositions

Sorry if this has been asked before, but it's kind of hard to search for the word "of".

Is it grammatically correct to say "I'm not familiar with all his works.", or is it necessary to say "I'm not familiar with all **of** his works."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but corpus evidence suggests a strong preference for the omission of *of*.